# How to make a Promoted Tile a size of 128x128

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, promoted-links

I am trying to make a promoted tile a size of 128x128, but for some reason on some of the tiles I see the tile being filled in with the color green on the right part of the image even though my image has no green.  If I change the size to 200x200 the green color is removed from the right part of the image and my image is seen as I would expect, but not at its smaller size.

How do I get the image at 128x128 and for the image to look "normal" other than being smaller.

Here is the CSS that seems to be the problem.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .ms-tileview-tile-content IMG {
    WIDTH:128 px !important; HEIGHT: 128px!important
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<style type="text/css">
  .ms-tileview-tile-content{
    WIDTH: 128px !important; 
    HEIGHT: 128px !important;
  }
</style
```

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between the .ms-tileview-tile-content in your post and the div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > img found in the post from Murphy

Answer (score 0):

I often use the following. You just need to adjust heights and widths. Read the comments between /* */ what it is you're editing.

```
/*  tile row height */
div.ms-promlink-body {
    height: 100px;
}
/*  tile dimensions, including inter-tile margin */
div.ms-tileview-tile-root {
    width: 110px !important;
    height: 110px !important;
}
/*  tile and title( + description) overlay dimensions */
div.ms-tileview-tile-content, div.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox {
    width: 100px !important;
    height: 100px !important;
}
/*  tile background image dimensions */
div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
/*  title and description text  */
ul.ms-tileview-tile-detailsListMedium {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 4px 7px 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
/*  description text class  */
li.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium {
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
/*  title text when description not shown  */
div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 86px;
    height: 29px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -33px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 4px 7px 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 13px;
}
.ms-promlink-headerNav {
    display: none;
}
```